# configuring emacs for cmake

Tags: emacs, cmake

gcc 4.4.2
cmake 2.6

I have just started using cmake. Coming from writing my own Makefiles.

However, I have this directory structure and using out-of-source build. To separate the source files from the build files.

```
project
    src
        my_c_files.c
        CMakeLists.txt
    build
        Makefile
```

Before I would write my own Makefiles in the src directory and then press F5 and I was able to compile my program. And emacs would list any warning or errors. However, it seems that I have to open a terminal and go to the build directory to run

```
cmake ../src
```

and then

```
make
```

I would like to run make from within emacs the same as pressing F5. But as the Makefile as been generated in the build directory, and emacs is looking for it in the src directory.

Even when I set a soft link to the Makefile in the src directory to link to the Makefile in the build directory. All this did was give me a list of errors.

Comment: Can you set compile-command to be "cmake ../src && make", or do you need to do something more complicated?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I will try your suggestion as soon as I am at my computer.

Comment: Hello, I did try that and it worked. As long as I am in the src directory. However, when I am in the client directory working on client.c. In the src/client/client.c it doesn't work. Even though I tried this 'cmake ../../src && make'. It wrote the build files, but it gives a message "No targets specified and no makefile found". I think I am looking for a way to compile my program in any directory that I currently working on. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For exactly the same purpose I found `.dir-locals.el` to be *extremely* helpful, here's how one of mine looks like:

```
((nil . ((tab-width . 8)
     (indent-tabs-mode . t)))
 (c++-mode . ((c-basic-offset . 8)
          (tab-width . 8)
          (indent-tabs-mode . t)
          (compile-command . "make -C ../build -j 2 run_tests")))
 ((c-mode . ((c-basic-offset . 8)
         (tab-width . 8)
         (indent-tabs-mode . t)
         (compile-command . "make -C ../build -j 2 run_tests")))))
```

Obviously I can have paths specified in different `.dir_locals.el` according to their location and such, say some build `run_tests` for unit test, some build the real target and so on.

Then I put a dummy `makefile` in the build directory, which looks like this:

```
all: run_tests

run_tests:
    @cmake ..
    @make -j 2
```

This way I can make a checkout and just run `M-x compile` in whichever file I like and it will do the right thing. I use git and have that Makefile *ignored* from monitoring by git like so:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged Makefile`

and if I want to modify and commit it I do

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Makefile`.

This way the newly created by cmake Makefile won't show in `git status` as modified, and I won't commit it accidentally.

Benefits of this approach:

- since cmake uses absolute paths internally, there's absolutely no problem jumping through compilation errors in compilation buffer by just pressing enter on them.
- you can specify whatever indentation rules you want there, and they can be different in different projects or even directories if you so please :)
- you can specify any amount of targets you want in different projects, even directories, still use the same old `M-x compile` (I have it bound to `C-c b`) and get Emacs to do *the right thing*.

The only drawback there is having `.dir-locals.el` in your subdirectories, which I hardly find bad.

**EDIT:** robUK, to answer your comment:

Here is [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) for *Per-Directory Local Variables* as they call it in Emacs manual. It is not a package, it's a part of Emacs, although I'm not sure if it was available in pre-23 versions, I'm using 23.1.1.

**EDIT2:** liwp, to answer your question:

As Charles already pointed out, and as documentation says:

> If you put a file with a special name
>   .dir-locals.el in a directory, Emacs
>   will read it when it visits any file
>   in that directory or any of its
>   subdirectories, and apply the settings
>   it specifies to the file's buffer.
>   Emacs searches for .dir-locals.el
>   starting in the directory of the
>   visited file, and moving up the
>   directory tree. (To avoid slowdown,
>   this search is skipped for remote
>   files.)

You don't need `.dir-locals.el` everywhere in your project tree. Note, however, it probably depends on the complexity of your code base structure.

I normally would go for a fairly simple layout like this:

```
/project_root_dir
    /build
    /src
    /test
```

and I would have slightly different targets specified in different `.dir-locals.el`, say in `/test` I would only build `testrunner` and have it executed, I'd spend most of the development time building this target. Then in `/src` I would first build the same `testrunner`, have it executed,and if everything goes well there, it would build me my main project target. If you don't need this, you could be fine with just one `.dir-locals.el` under `/project_root_dir`. If your source structure and requirements are a lot more sophisticated, it could mean you'd need a bit more path- and target-related wizardry.

Comment: Hello, this looks good. Where can I download the package dir-locals.el. Any documentation on how to use it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that. Currently I am using 23.1.1.

Comment: @Dmitry: just to clarify, do you need to have a `.dir-locals.el` file in _each_ subdirectory for this to work? I'm working on a large scale project with a huge `src` tree and I can't add emacs-specific files to the repo so I would have to generate the `.dir-local.el` files each time I check out...

Comment: @liwp: No, .dir-locals.el files apply to subdirectories.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer. I will I could have marked everyone correct.

Comment: when running 'cmake ..' in build directory, cmake will write its 'Makefile' which overwrites makefile you customed.

Answer (score 9):

A more general solution for compile-command would be:

```
cd ${PWD%/src/*}/build && cmake ../src && make
```

The environment variable PWD holds the directory the file you're editing is in; expanding it with `%/src/*` gets you back to the project root without having to worry about how many `../`s you need.

Comment: More elegant still is `cd ${PWD/%src*/build} && cmake ../src && make` to use bash's regexp-replace machinery. Need to be wary of escaping backslashes if you use any more of them, though.

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution:
install [cpputils-cmake](https://github.com/redguardtoo/cpputils-cmake), then you are good to go.

Explanation:
CMake already put all the information in the build directory. You just need hack the ELisp variable `compile-command` in your `c++-mode-hook` and `c-mode-hook` if you get the right information from cmake.

Two points for a perfect solution:

1. You elisp code should detect whether current project is using CMake by scanning source directory before hacking `compile-command`
2. The out-of-source build directory's full path should be *automatically* detected and appended to the `make -C` command.

I wrote an emacs plugin `cpputils-cmake` https://github.com/redguardtoo/cpputils-cmake which will solve these two issues. Check my code and you can install it though Emacs's package manager.

BTW, 
After build directory is created by cmake, usually cmake should not be explicitly called in the command line. `make -C out-of-source-build-dir` is smart enough because the Makefile in that directory will call cmake anyway. Even after you change CMakeLists.txt, calling `make -C out-of-source-build-dir` is still enough. I'm pretty sure about this because I've been using cmake for four years.

Many previous answers won't work because:

1. Any assumption about source tree layout could be wrong. For example, I name my root source directory to "mysrc" instead of "src"
2. How I use out-of-source strategy is complicated. For example, I may build only one component by using out-of-source.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using EDE from Cedet to configure projects for work with CMake. Look [into my CEDET config](http://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el), starting with line 105, for example of code for project configuration.  I use separate Debug & Release directories for different builds, and by default, compilation is running only for Debug mode....

Comment: I am quite new to emacs, and I have never written in lisp. I think you are setting the path to your CMakelists.txt and your boost libraries. However, I am not sure about this. cons 'compile-command 'alexott/gen-cmake-debug-compile-string" For my .emacs I have the following (global-set-key [f5] 'compile). Any suggestions would be most helpfull. Thanks.

Comment: my configuration uses F9 - see line 165
it works following way. 'cons compile-command ...' is used to setup process-specific compilation command, that will applicable only for concrete project.  This command will take project root directory, determined from ':file path_to_cmakelists.txt' and will perform 'cd PROJECT_ROOT/Debug; make -j2'

Answer (score 2):

You can change the current working directory that emacs uses with `M-x cd<enter> <path to build dir><enter>`. After this, when you run `M-x compile`, `make` will be executed in the new working directory. This is effectively the same as running `make` on the terminal in the build directory, so it should work for you just fine.

Answer (score 2):

How about using -C option for make ?

Press <kbd>F5</kbd>, or `M-x compile`, when emacs asks compile-command, type:

```
make -C ../build
```

Comment: why editing my post? F5 is not set to compile command in all emacs, and is not by default on my installation, so the command M-x compile is more appropriate, up to people to bind it to some fkeys

Answer (score 1):

Change the command to use the absolute instead of relative pat.  EG:

```
cmake ~/workspace/project/src && make
```